# No Errors with Transpose Function and No Change In Result

Tags: python, csv, pandas, transpose

I am having difficulty making use of a transpose functions made available through pandas and scipy:

My issue is that I am saving to a csv file in a single column with several rows, when in fact it should be the other way around (several columns and a single row).

Here is what I am working with (an average of values based on a pandas setup - "pd"):

```
mid = pd.read_csv("Experiment12.csv",usecols=[0,1,2],skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]).mean()
```

Do the functions like `mid.T` work on pandas?

I receive no errors and when checking the results nothing has changed, I still have the single column with all the values in rows.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write using a single column `DataFrame` just fine:

```
import pandas.util.testing as tm
from pandas import read_csv

df = tm.makeTimeDataFrame()
dfa = df[['A']].T
dfa.to_csv('the_csv.csv')
dfa_hat = read_csv('the_csv.csv', index_col=0)
dfa_hat.T
```

But I suspect that isn't your problem. You're misunderstanding that when you call `DataFrame.mean()` you're performing a reduction along an axis (`axis == 0` by default).

Let's look at a simple example:

```
In [272]: df = DataFrame(randn(5, 2), columns=list('ab'))

In [273]: df
Out[273]:
       a      b
0  0.056 -0.056
1 -0.384  1.153
2  0.524 -1.545
3  1.082  1.665
4 -0.593 -0.412

In [274]: df.mean()
Out[274]:
a    0.137
b    0.161
dtype: float64

In [275]: type(df.mean())
Out[275]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Notice that the `index` of `df.mean()` is the `columns` of `df`. That's because I reduced across the rows. Also notice that `type(df.mean())` is `Series` which is the `pandas` equivalent of numpy array with a single axis, that is, a vector. This is by design. It may *look* like a column when it prints out to the console, but it behaves pretty much identically to `numpy` arrays with respect to when it is treated as a column versus a row by `numpy`.

In `pandas` however, `Series` objects are always treated like columns except in cases where rows are explicitly requested by the user. For example, the rows of a `DataFrame` can be accessed as `Series` objects (though this is often inefficient with heterogeneous columns). This is how `numpy` works too: individual rows and columns are 1D arrays.

So to answer your question, just like a 1D `numpy` array returns itself when `T` is called on it, so will a `Series` object.